# Finding a Specific Line of a File Using Numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am using matplotlib to make a weight chart with information from a file that contains both text and numbers. The numbers are two lines that have the weights and the dates in them. The file looks like this:

```
1. anonymous 
2. anonymous
3. 
4. 34, 76
5. 12202018, 12222018
```

I want to use numpy to retreive the weight (3rd line) and the date (4th line), but I can't find a way to just retrieve one line to plot in matplotlib.

I have tried to do it with csv, but it didn't work because when you make a list to retrieve just one line, you can't plot that line in the list. My code was:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv

x = []
y = []

with 
open('example.txt') as csvfile:
    readCSV = list(csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ','))
    row3 = readCSV[3]

    for row in row3:
        x.append(int(row[0]))
        y.append(int(row[1]))

plt.plot(x, y)

plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.title("Weight Chart")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

The error produced:

```
row3 = int(readCSV[3])
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'
```

---

Just to clarify:

I want to use numpy to retrieve one line of a file (with the delimeter of ',') to use as a x and y axis for matplotlib.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Use ordinary python line reads to get the desired line.  Then extract the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will get the values from the file into your arrays:

```
def process(line):
    line = line.rstrip()
    line = line.split('.')[1]
    line = line.split(',')
    return line

x = list()
y = list()
counter = 0
with open('example.txt') as data_file:
    for line in data_file:
        if (counter == 3) or (counter == 4):
            result = process(line)
            x.append(int(result[0]))
            y.append(int(result[1]))
        counter += 1

print x
print y
```

Comment: Thanks so much! It produces the error 'line = line.split('.')[1]
IndexError: list index out of range'

Comment: @EMCMAHE Put print(line) before that line of code to see why.

Comment: Thank you so much again for your help. I am a beginner so I don't really know hoe to fix it so if you could give me more help that would be great!! Thx again!